# Spring: access primary beans via ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, autowired

If I have 2 beans in my ApplicationContext implementing the same interface I can mark one of them as primary in the bean definition. This bean is prefered for dependency injection.

Is there a way to get direct access using the ApplicationContext to the primary one without DI?

Comment: This is a known bug in Spring 3.0, which has been fixed in Spring 3.2: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7854

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need your BeanFactory/ApplicationContext. You can retrieve it for example by implementing BeanFactoryAware. Assuming it is ConfigurableListableBeanFactory, you can check what's primary for given type like this:

```
  ConfigurableListableBeanFactory clbf =
        (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory)beanFactory;
  String[] beanNames = clbf.getBeanNamesForType(myType);
  for (String beanName : beanNames) {
     BeanDefinition bd = clbf.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
     if (bd.isPrimary()) {
        ...
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

There are many different ways to do this.

1. Set primary="true" in the primary bean definition. When this is set, if there are multiple candidates for auto wiring, the primary will be given the higher priority.

   ```
   <beans ...>
     <bean id="myPrimaryBeanId" class="mypackage.MyInterface" primary="true"/>
     <bean id="mySecondaryBeanId" class="mypackage.MyInterface" />
   </beans>
   ```
2. Alternatively, set autowire-candidate="false" for the non primary beans, if you think this bean should not be auto wired in to any bean at all. However, need to be careful when defining another bean with the same interface, as if you forget to add this, there will again be multiple primary beans.

   ```
   <beans ...>
     <bean id="myPrimaryBeanId" class="mypackage.MyInterface"/>
     <bean id="mySecondaryBeanId" class="mypackage.MyInterface"
         autowire-candidate="false"/>
   </beans>
   ```
3. Be more specific on the auto wiring annotations by using named dependencies, which can be archvied by using @javax.annotation.Resource annotation as shown below. This will reduce the code complexity of figuring out which bean could have been injected, as one can simply locate the bean by id.

   ```
   @Resource(name="myPrimaryBeanId")
   protected MyInterface myInstance;
   ```

**Non Dependency Injection (DI) method**

If you prefer not to use DI, you can use the following to fetch the bean by name from the ApplicationContext

```
MyInterface myInstance = (MyInterface) 
    applicationContext.getBean("myPrimaryBeanId");
```

If you want to do with non DI method, but from a spring bean, and if you do not have a handle to the spring context to do it, you can change your class to implement the org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware interface, which will require you to implement the setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext) method, in to which spring will inject the handle to the current application context as shown below.

```
public class MyBean implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  private String MY_PRIMARY_BEAN_ID = "myPrimaryBeanId";

  public void myMethod() {
    MyInterface myInstance = getMyPrimaryBean();

    // do my logic here
  }

  private MyInterface getMyPrimaryBean() {
    return (MyInterface) applicationContext.getBean(MY_PRIMARY_BEAN_ID);
  }

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
      throws BeansException {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

}
```

**Note:** This answer is based on Spring 2.5.x

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it as Bean and set the dependency manually by fetching from ApplicationContext and setting it . But you will break *Inversion of Control*

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case I can't decide which bean is the primary one, because I can only fetch the name and the bean itself from the context. I have no access to the bean definition meta data.

Comment: Having two beans with the same id in the context is not really save. Sometimes it works, but it is not recommended by Spring.

Comment: I am confused. Can you please restate your issue